# Problema con un anchor dentro de un position fixed. (CSS Pure)

Tags: html, css, position

Estoy intentando crear un simple logo que diriga a la página principal al hacer click en el, para mantenerlo siempre en la misma posición al hacer scroll, utilicé position fixed, pero, al hacer scroll este por alguna razón deja de funcionar como anchor y pasa solo a texto.

```css
.header-title{
    position: fixed;
    font-family: 'Druk Wide Bold', sans-serif;
    font-size: xx-large;
    left: 1em;
    top: 1em;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/druk-wide-bold" rel="stylesheet">        
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/d949c6494b.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>


    <div class="header-title">
        
        <a href="index.html" class="logo">César <br> Hernán <br> Dez.</a>
       
    </div>
```

HTML

```
<div class="header-title">
    
    <a href="index.html" class="logo">César <br> Hernán <br> Dez.</a>
   
</div>
```

CSS

```
.header-title{
position: fixed;
font-family: 'Druk Wide Bold', sans-serif;
font-size: xx-large;
left: 1em;
top: 1em;
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
```

}

Aclarar que, ya intenté declarar los estilos al propio anchor, pero esto tampoco funcionó

Comment: debe haber algo que queda por encima ( right click inspect debería mostrarte que es lo que captura los clicks ), proba cambiarle el z-index al fixed

Comment: Usa un Snippet y muestra todo el código usado para recrearlo.

Comment: @OCHOA Ya lo hice amigo, pero me encontré la sorpresa de que acá si sigue funcionando el anchor, sin embargo en mi host local no, no entiendo a que se pueda deber eso.

Comment: @aloMalbarez Gracias por la recomendación, sin embargo lo probé y no funcionó tampoco

Comment: El clásico: _¿limpiaste la caché?_

Comment: Difícil si funciona acá y en tu ambiente no...

Comment: @padaleiana del navegador te refieres? soy nuevo por acá

Comment: @OCHOA Sí, no sé a qué se deberá

Comment: Usa una sesión de incognito para evitar un poco temas de caché.

Comment: @ElyAlfaro Sí. Probá recargar la página con `Ctrl + F5` (en Firefox; si mal no recuerdo es `Shift + F5` en navegadores basados en Chromium)

Comment: presiona F12, en la consola tipea `document.addEventListener('click', (e)=> console.log(e.target))` y hace click en el anchor a ver q dice

Comment: Evidentemente no sabemos que sucede en tu computadora. Tal vez hay un elemento transparente que pasa por encima de tu link. Prueba darle un z-index. Tampoco se sabe que hacen los scripts que tienes, tal vez alguno le cambie el comportamiento. Pero una cosa que podrías tratar es darle los estilos al link en lugar del contenedor incluyendo asignarle un display:block; Eso quizá ayude, y también mejorará la usabilidad, ya que ahorita tienes tres renglones clickeables. Al asignarle un display:block lo convertirás en un solo objeto clickeable. También te asegurarás de que quien esté fixed sea tu lin